# SharePoint Visitor Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have a Visitors Group in my Site. This Group has default Read Access. I did not customize the Permission Level. I added an user to Visitors Group.

My question is, can a visitor add Documents to the Library. I logged in as a visitor and I could add documents to the Library. My understanding was that Visitors can only see but cannot add items. Kindly correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add users to multiple groups, as well as you can give direct permissions.

So once user login SharePoint will evaluate the permission and assign the top most.

For ex: If user is in Reader Group and user is an owner of library. Then user can add documents only to that Library while he will be able to read from all other places (like list, pages etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Visitors with read permissions cannot add normally. I would try logging into the site in a different browser, preferably Chrome in Incognito mode to be sure that is the case. Sharepoint has an awful habit of caching credentials even though you think you've signed out.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen to me and it's because I started a new IE browser that thought I was still logged in with owner permissions.
I always test with Chrome or Firefox so that I know there are no cached account details.

Answer (score 2):

By default a `Visitor group` assigned to Read Permission level. Read permission level has following permissions:

```
View Application Pages
Browse User Information
Use Remote Interfaces
Use Client Integration Features
Open
View Items
Open Items
View Versions
Create Alerts
Use Self-Service Site Creation
View Pages
```

So, their is no add item permission it. Now, if user with read permission still able to upload the documents then you should check the permission for that user in site collection. To check the user permission:

- `Site settings> site permission >`on this page from Ribbon click on `Search user`

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/check-the-user-permissions-in-sharepoint-2013-online/